# When was drag and drop first possible in browsers?

Tags: browser, drag-and-drop, specifications

Well that's it... I can't seem to find it anywhere, and I'd really like to add that to my PhD thesis, as it pretty much relies on it (and the whole idea for it dates back to 2005 od 2006). I googled around but to no avail, so I hope someone remembers... tnx in advance!

EDIT: possible solution - browser support chart. Check buttons "Show all" and "Date relative". Seems like Safari 3.1 (03.2008.) was the first one to fully support, but I'm still not sure, will keep searching.
http://caniuse.com/#search=drop

Comment: JavaScript ... I mean, I don't even know how to phrase this; the concept of "drag and drop" has nothing to do with JavaScript, and JavaScript the programming language has no built-in support for anything remotely like that. Are you really asking about when *browsers* began to support "drop" events?

Comment: The question should be in the question, don't leave it in the title. It's also off topic. :-( Drag and drop is not supported by javascript *per se*, however it's possible to implement drag and drop using javascript in a document (or any other host environment that supports suitable functionality).

Comment: You're right, it's about browser support... thnx Pointy! And about the question in the question part (RobG), I thought it would be pointless to repeat the question itself... why aks two times?

Comment: You might try asking on [*comp.lang.javascript*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.javascript), there are posters there who likely can advise the first versions of JavaScript and JScript that supported the related events. Take a flak jacket. ;-)

Comment: Aha, okay, I'll try that too, thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop itself has been around as a concept for much longer than it has been used in JavaScript. JavaScript itself does not have a "drag and drop module".

You might want to look at when events got added into JavaScript, i.e. onMouseDown and onMouseMove - which is what drag and drop scripts are based around. Next you might want to research when mousedown & mousemove actually got used together, to fulfil the drag and drop purpose.

Comment: Right. And strictly speaking, the events were added to *web browsers*, and made *available* to JavaScript. That may be what the OP actually means of course.

Comment: Right right, I got it... well, guess more googling ahead...

Comment: You could try looking through the original JavaScript spec from 1997 for clues, and then perhaps later versions. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf

Comment: Just did, nothing there... I'll look into other specifications too...

Comment: It's actually quite fascinating exploring the original spec, discovering what has actually been there since day one is pretty cool!

Comment: DOM is a key part of the JavaScript experience in the browser, and DOM does have events specifically for drag and drop. So it's not entirely correct to say that JavaScript doesn't have a drag and drop module.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're probably looking for is to another question:  "When was Drag-and-drop possible on the web, using javascript?" and I think that there could be considerable debate, depending on what elements you want to drag, and what exactly you mean by "drag".

Since most people would consider "drag" to mean "move with the cursor", my answer would be that it was possible at latest in 1998 when css was introduced, and absolute positioning of elements was possible.  (It may have been possible to absolute position before css, but I can't remember back that far).

Comment: One issue with current standards and specifications is that there is no indication of when features were introduced. MDN has lately been including a link to the initial definition for ECMAScript features, but that's much harder with DOM topics and it seems [*mousemove*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) goes too far back.

Comment: Hm, that's right... it's vague...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried google search trends? https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=2004-01-01%202017-03-25&q=%22javascript%20drag%20and%20drop%22

On a side note: here's a patent filed in 1997 that mentions drag and drop as an established term https://www.google.com/patents/US6008811

Comment: Google trends hahaaa never crossed my mind, thnx! :-) And that patent, it's probably the general patent (in OS GUIs)... at least it looks like such...